# JSON Parse: Not parsing with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I get JSON data with jquery.ajax and dataType is "JSON"  But I have some problem

This is my JSON data :

```
{
    "stock": {
        "head": [
            "name",
            "est",
            "date"
        ],
        "body": [
            {
                "row": [
                    "TEST",
                    "10.58",
                    "2013-09-05 13:37:20"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "year": {
        "head": [
            "name",
            "est",
            "date"
        ],
        "body": [
            {
                "row": [
                    "TEST",
                    "0",
                    "2013-09-05 13:37:35"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var getdata = $.ajax({
    type     :    'POST',
    url      :    'testjson.php',
    data     :    data,
    dataType :    'json'
});

getdata.done(function(result){

    var queryHead = result.stock.head; // This returns data
    var queryBody = result.stock.body; // But this doesn't return data. Empty

});
```

JSON data successfully returned, but not being parsed correctly. 
`queryHead` works fine but `queryBody` does not work

Comment: Seems like a problem with whatever is generating the JSON

Comment: I try in http://jsfiddle.net/ and work in there.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the data you think you're getting? Firebug (for Firefox) has a handy Net tab that can monitor network traffic and confirm that the data is what it should be.

Comment: @SonerGüler but you can't control what the server side sets with jsfiddle.net

Comment: You should be able to do some debugging on this yourself. Have you tried `console.log(result`) at least?

Comment: I solved. You are right. My data not return completely. Thank u.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is external to the code posted; the question is fundamentally unanswerable and not useful to future users.